# Add lots of seconds to TDateTime in C++Builder 2009

Tags: c++, time, tdatetime, c++builder-2009

I am using C++Builder 2009.  I have a start date `2000/01/01` and a count of seconds from this timestamp. I want to create a `TDateTime` with this date. I create a start point `TDateTime` and add seconds.

```
  TDateTime dt(2000,1,1,0,0,0,0);
  AnsiString sdt = "";
  DateTimeToString(sdt, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss", dt);
  closeDateTime = dt;
  closeDateTime = IncSecond(closeDateTime,footer->secondsFromZeroDateOfFinishDocument);
  DateTimeToString(sdt, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss", closeDateTime);
```

After add more than 650M seconds, the `TDateTime` increases by only 23 days, but should increase by more than 20 years. See screenshots below.

How can I add this number of seconds to a `TDateTime`?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code, and it would surprise me if `IncSeconds` was *that* broken.

Comment: I'm using C++ Builder 2009.

Comment: All bets are off if you're using a compiler from *11 years ago*.

Comment: I can't upgrade compiler.

Comment: C++ builder 2009 went end of life in 2011. You *have* to upgrade.

Comment: @Botje actually, in C++Builder/Delphi 2009 and even earlier, the `DateUtils` functions weren't very accurate. The functions were re-written in XE to address accuracy issues.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ... and that is why you don't use 11 year old compilers. Thank you for confirming my suspicion :)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code.  And in fact, I can't reproduce the issue you describe, using the values you have shown.  The output I get is `2020.09.30 08:32:21`, as expected.

---

That being said, the functions in the `DateUtils` unit were known to have accuracy issues prior to XE, when those issues were fixed.  C++Builder 2009 predates XE.  So, if you can't upgrade to an up-to-date version, you can at least apply the same fix that is being used in later versions:

```cpp
#include <SysUtils.hpp>

namespace fixed {
    TDateTime __fastcall IncSecond(const TDateTime AValue, const __int64 ANumberOfSeconds = 1)
    {
        TTimeStamp TS = DateTimeToTimeStamp(AValue);
        double TempTime = TimeStampToMSecs(TS);
        // if the above call to TimeStampToMSecs() proves to be inaccurate (it did
        // in my test in C++, but worked fine in Delphi), you can use this instead:
        // double TempTime = (double(TS.Date) * double(MSecsPerDay)) + double(TS.Time);
        TempTime = TempTime + (ANumberOfSeconds * MSecsPerSec);
        TS = MSecsToTimeStamp(TempTime);
        return TimeStampToDateTime(TS);
    }
}

TDateTime dt(2000,1,1,0,0,0,0);
AnsiString sdt = "";
DateTimeToString(sdt, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss", dt);
closeDateTime = dt;
closeDateTime = fixed::IncSecond(closeDateTime,footer->secondsFromZeroDateOfFinishDocument);
DateTimeToString(sdt, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss", closeDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some work around. I add days, and then add rest of seconds. I thik this is bug in RTL but I can't upgrade this codebase.

```
  TDateTime dt(2000,1,1,0,0,0,0);
  AnsiString sdt = "";
  DateTimeToString(sdt, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss", dt);
  closeDateTime = dt;
  int seconds = footer->secondsFromZeroDateOfFinis775hDocument;
  int days = seconds / 86400;
  int restOfSeconds = seconds - days*86400;
  closeDateTime = IncDay(closeDateTime,days);
  closeDateTime = IncSecond(closeDateTime,restOfSeconds);
  DateTimeToString(sdt, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss", closeDateTime);
```

Comment: FYI, `int restOfSeconds = seconds - days*86400;` can be simplified to `int restOfSeconds = seconds % 86400;` and you can use the `Syutils::SecsPerDay` constant instead of hard-coding `86400`.